# Alignment of labels in tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

Please consider the following example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,step=5mm,gray!20] (-3,-2) grid (4,3);
\draw (-2,-1) -- (2,-1);
\draw (-2,2) -- (2,2);
\draw (-2,2) -- (-2,-1) node[midway, sloped, below] {\footnotesize subalterns};
\draw (2,2) -- (2,-1) node[midway, sloped, above] {\footnotesize subalterns};
\node [above left] at (-2,2) {Every};
\node [above right] at (2,2) {No};
\node [below left] at (-2,-1) {Some};
\draw (-2,2) -- (0,0.5) node[anchor=mid, midway, sloped] {\footnotesize contradic};
\draw (0,0.5) -- (2,-1) node[midway, sloped] {\footnotesize tories};
\draw (-2,-1) -- (0,0.5) node[anchor=mid, midway, sloped] {\footnotesize contradic};
\draw (0,0.5) -- (2,2) node[anchor=mid, midway, sloped] {\footnotesize tories};
\node [below right, text width=1.9cm] at (2,-1) {Not every or not any};
\draw[decoration={calligraphic brace,mirror, amplitude=5pt}, decorate, line width=1pt] (-2.7,-1.5) node {} -- (2.7,-1.5);
\draw[decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=5pt}, decorate, line width=1pt] (-2.7,2.5) node {} -- (2.7,2.5);
\node at (0, 2.9) {Contraries};
\node at (0, -1.9) {Subcontraries};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

As you can see, there are two problems (which I think are interconnected) with the labels: a) Labels "Every" and "No" are not aligned with each other (curiously, they do if instead of "No" I type "No (...)"); b) The labels on the diagonal lines (which I would like to display without the line) do not seem to be centered, i.e., they are not placed at the same distance from the point where the two diagonals cross (0,0.5). Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because these nodes have different depths and heights. One way to fix it is to synchronize the depths and heights of all nodes, which can be achieved by adding

```
nodes={text depth=0.25ex,text height=1.25ex}
```

to the options of the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text depth=0.25ex,text height=1.25ex}]
\draw[help lines,step=5mm,gray!20] (-3,-2) grid (4,3);
\draw (-2,-1) -- (2,-1);
\draw (-2,2) -- (2,2);
\draw (-2,2) -- (-2,-1) node[midway, sloped, below] {\footnotesize subalterns};
\draw (2,2) -- (2,-1) node[midway, sloped, above] {\footnotesize subalterns};
\node [above left] at (-2,2) {Every};
\node [above right] at (2,2) {No};
\node [below left] at (-2,-1) {Some};
\draw (-2,2) -- (0,0.5) node[anchor=mid, midway, sloped] {\footnotesize contradic};
\draw (0,0.5) -- (2,-1) node[midway, sloped] {\footnotesize tories};
\draw (-2,-1) -- (0,0.5) node[anchor=mid, midway, sloped] {\footnotesize contradic};
\draw (0,0.5) -- (2,2) node[anchor=mid, midway, sloped] {\footnotesize tories};
\node [below right, text width=1.9cm] at (2,-1) {Not every or not any};
\draw[decoration={calligraphic brace,mirror, amplitude=5pt}, decorate, line width=1pt] (-2.7,-1.5) node {} -- (2.7,-1.5);
\draw[decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=5pt}, decorate, line width=1pt] (-2.7,2.5) node {} -- (2.7,2.5);
\node at (0, 2.9) {Contraries};
\node at (0, -1.9) {Subcontraries};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to remove the lines where the nodes are, you can use Rmano's suggestion to add `fill=white`. Since the paths are all of the same lengths, you can position them away from the same distance by using `pos=0.15`, say, and dial appropriate anchors. And I recommend using symbolic coordinates such that you can make adjustments more easily.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text depth=0.25ex,text height=1.25ex}]
 \draw[help lines,step=5mm,gray!20] (-3,-2) grid (4,3);
 \draw (-2,-1) coordinate (BL) node [below left]{Some} -- 
  (2,-1) coordinate (BR) node[below right, text width=1.9cm]  {Not every or not any} --
  (2,2) coordinate (TR) node[above right] {No} -- 
  (-2,2) coordinate (TL) node [above left] {Every}
  -- cycle (0,0.5) coordinate (M);
 \begin{scope}[font=\footnotesize]
  \path (TL) -- (BL) node[midway, sloped, below] {subalterns};
  \path (TR) -- (BR) node[midway, sloped, above] {subalterns};
  \begin{scope}[nodes={pos=0.15, sloped,fill=white}]
   \draw (M) -- (TL) node[anchor=east] {contradic};
   \draw (M) -- (BR) node[anchor=west] {tories};
   \draw (M) -- (BL) node[anchor=east] {contradic};
   \draw (M) -- (TR) node[anchor=west] {tories};
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 \draw[decoration={calligraphic brace,mirror, amplitude=5pt}, decorate, line width=1pt] (-2.7,-1.5)  -- (2.7,-1.5);
 \draw[decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=5pt}, decorate, line width=1pt]
 (-2.7,2.5)  -- (2.7,2.5);
 \node at (0, 2.9) {Contraries};
 \node at (0, -1.9) {Subcontraries};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @marmot. I need the lines, but not where "contradic" and "tories" are placed. `draw` doesn't seem to fix the problem. Also, how do I place these four labels ("contradic" and "tories") so that they're all at the same distance from the centre? In other words, the distance between the end of "contradic" and the centre of the rectangle must be the same as the distance between the centre of the rectangle and the beginning of "tories".

Comment: You can draw the lines and `fill` the text nodes with white. Obviously, when I will finish to type this comment and press "enter", @marmot will have edited the answer already (sorry if the conditional is wrong...)

Comment: @Catoblepa Please see Rmano's nice comment and give me a few minutes to finish my wheat beer. ;-)

Comment: @Catoblepa Wheat beer finished.

Comment: @Rmano Gracias! (Or grazie?)

Comment: @marmot thank you (I owe you a beer)! (and Rmano: grazie!)

Comment: @marmot both are ok ;-)