# The position of the function formula

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to place the function formula above the function as in the example.

My code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[style=help lines, dashdotted, gray, thick] (-2,4) grid (3,-2);
    \tkzInit[xmax=4,ymax=4,xmin=-3,ymin=-2]
    \tkzAxeXY
    \draw[scale=1, domain=-1.2:2.2, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {-(\x*\x)+\x+2}) node [pos=0.6, above right, black] {$y=-x^2+x+2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Example:
[image: Example:]

Comment: Hi, see the source https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498510/alignment-of-labels-in-tikz-nodes

Comment: Why are you using `tkz-fct` and not the `\tkzFct` macro to draw your curve? You can draw this example either with a complete `tkz-fct` script or in plain Ti*k*Z but it should be consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy  with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, pstricks, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot, multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2.5)(4.5,4.5)
\psset{algebraic, plotpoints=100, showorigin=false, arrowinset=0.15, linejoin=1, gridcoor={(-1,-1)(3,3)}}
\multido{\i=-1+1}{5}{\psset{linewidth=0.5pt, linestyle=dashed, linecolor=Gainsboro}\psline(-2,\i)(3,\i)}
\multido{\i=-1+1}{4}{\psset{linewidth=0.5pt, linestyle=dashed, linecolor=Gainsboro}\psline(\i, -2)(\i,4)}
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,ticksize=-2pt 2pt, linecolor=LightSteelBlue]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-2.5)(4.5,4.5)[$x$,-120][$y$,210]
\psset{linewidth=1pt,algebraic, linecolor=IndianRed}
\psplot[linecolor=RoyalBlue] {-1.5}{2.5}{-x^2+x+2}
\uput{0.5em}[ur](0.5,2.25){$-x^2+x+2$}
\uput[dl](0,0){$\scriptstyle 0$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, let's admit that you want to use `tkz-fct` only for the grid and axes, and that you don't want to install `gnuplot` (I'm OK with that). So you can draw your curve and place your equation in two separate commands:

[image: Formula positioning]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
        \tkzInit[xmin=-2,xmax=4,ymin=-2,ymax=4]
        \tkzGrid
        \tkzAxeXY
        \clip (-2,-2) rectangle (4,4);
        \draw[domain=-2:4, smooth, variable=\x, blue, thick] plot ({\x}, {-(\x*\x)+\x+2});
        \node[right] at (0.5,2.5) {$y=-x^2+x+2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```